# Issue when parsing string date from CSV in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, date, parsing, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to parse a string date from a CSV in a Jupyter notebook:

```
from datetime import datetime
print(datetime.strptime('Aug 28, 2022', 'MMM d, yyyy'))
```

but I get the following error:

```
ValueError: time data 'Aug 28, 2022' does not match format 'MMM d, yyyy'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use other format string ([format codes reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)):

```py
from datetime import datetime

print(datetime.strptime("Aug 28, 2022", "%b %d, %Y"))
```

Prints:

```
2022-08-28 00:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks from the newbie here...

Answer (score 1):

Use the following format

```
from datetime import datetime
print(datetime.strptime('Aug 28, 2022','%b %d, %Y'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out

```
from datetime import datetime
print (datetime.strptime ('Aug 28, 2022', '%b %d, %Y'))
```

To know about basic formats,
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-datetime-strptime-function/

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution is:

```
datetime.strptime('Aug 28, 2022', '%b %d, %Y')
```

See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-datetime-strptime-function/

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:([Explanation with samples](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strptime))

We use notation that starts with **%** in `datatime.strptime`

```py
datetime.strptime("Aug 28, 2022", "%b %d, %Y")
```

Thank you :)